# ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all() Python Sagemaker XGBoost

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to get predictions from a model file.

My dataframe df has the following data:

```
target,feature1,feature2
0,0.8571428571428571,31.72975
0,2.0,27.525
0,1.0,47.11675
0,1.0,29.15
0,0.0,42.483000000000004
0,2.0,40.85825
0,0.0,34.97525
1,0.8571428571428571,31.72975
1,0.0,0.0
0,0.8571428571428571,31.72975
```

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pickle as pkl
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import xgboost as xgb


df  = pd.read_csv("input.csv")

# Handle Nan values if any 
df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True)
df.fillna(df.mean(), inplace=True)
df[~df.isin([np.nan, np.inf, -np.inf]).any(1)].astype(np.float64)

# Split Features and Target    
X = df.drop(columns="target")
y = df["target"]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

# Load the model from disk
model = pkl.load(open('xgboost-model', 'rb'))
results = model.predict(X_test, y_test)
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 32, in <module>
    results = model.predict(X_test, y_test)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py", line 1348, in predict
    if output_margin:
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1330, in __nonzero__
    f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

On this line model.predict(X_test, y_test)

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `results = model.predict(xgb.DMatrix(X_test.values))` since you want to have predictions for your test dataset `X_test`.
`results` includes your model predictions that can be compared to your actual test dataset `y_test`, preferably with an evaluation metric.

Comment: I get another error TypeError: ('Expecting data to be a DMatrix object, got: ', <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>)

Comment: It should actually be model.predict(xgb.DMatrix(X_test.values)). Can you please update the answer? I will accept it. Thank you for your time.